# Excel graph axes starts from 0 when range is large?

Tags: excel, plot, graph

I'm experiencing some strange excel plots, where the x-axis starts from 0 instead of starting from the minimum value it's being plotted against.

This happens only when the range of the x values exceeds approximately 2100?

Please see the figures I've shown below:

[image]

[image]

What is going on, and how do I force it to start from the minimum values by default? I'm aware that I can change it under axis properties, but I think this should happen by default.